# denied: Permission "artifactregistry.repositories.downloadArtifacts" denied on resource

Tags: visual-studio-code, google-artifact-registry

i am using VSCODE to push image which is stored in Docker repo locally to GCP Artifact repo.
i ran gcloud auth configure-docker us-west1-docker.pkg.dev command in GCP console and while pushing image from VSCODE I got below error

```
command :-docker push us-west1-docker.pkg.dev/xxx/reponame/test-image

59769727d80: Waiting
348622fdcc61: Waiting
4ac8bc2cd0be: Waiting
denied: Permission "artifactregistry.repositories.downloadArtifacts" denied on resource "projects/xxx/locations/us-west1/repositories/reponame" (or it may not exist)
```

Comment: Can you check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/authentication#gcloud-helper) thoroughly and see if you are following all the 4 steps? Make sure the credential helpers are in the system PATH same as that of the gcloud commands.

Comment: Note: If you normally run Docker commands on Linux with sudo, Docker looks for Artifact Registry credentials in /root/.docker/config.json instead of $HOME/.docker/config.json. If you want to use sudo with docker commands instead of using the Docker security group, configure credentials with sudo gcloud auth configure-docker instead.